# White screen of death after activating my custom theme on bluehost

Tags: php, wordpress

I am currently developing a theme which i was working on local environment using xampp and it was working fine till i uploaded my theme on live host in my case i am using bluehost. After i activated the theme i got white screen of death. I then tried uploading my theme using cpanel file manager and filezilla, but i got the same issue. After that i tried another local environment "Wordpress by bitnami"and it was working fine there too. I dont know whats wrong with my theme. I also increased the limit of my wordpress memory limit. Here is the download link for my theme. Please help me out i am totally stuck :( https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4HLAyVud6iLMGx4NUtxaXpJb00 . I searched all the web but i cant find solution for my problem.

Comment: white screen of death: error checking\display are off, turn them on to see the error. at the top of your php page add: `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); ini_set('html_errors', 0); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: @rtfm which file are you referring me to put this code in?

Comment: Try adding this code in your wp-config.php `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` not in live site in your local dev.

Comment: @RajendranNadar Its giving this warning Warning: require(/home2/spectaf7/public_html/wp-content/themes/sp/redux-framework/reduxcore/framework.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home2/spectaf7/public_html/wp-content/themes/sp/functions.php on line 23

Comment: @RajendranNadar i dont understanding why it is not linking to this path. Which is working fine on localhosts.

Comment: This is what is causing the issue fix that. Put the code that is causing that issue.

Comment: Check with error log. I guess this is due to memory issue not sure